# What is the actual differance between type2 and type 4 driver in Jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I have listened that type 2 driver needs some database library's apis. I cant understand above statement can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Just a paragraph snippet from [this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21335778) link. Also, visit the helpful link : [JDBC Driver and Its Types](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-driver-and-its-types.shtml)

> Type 2: Requires the DB2 Client is
>   also installed on the same server as
>   the JDBC driver because the driver is
>   simply a front-end to the DB2 Client.
>   It points to the alias you configured
>   on the Client for your database,
>   similar to an ODBC driver.
>
> Type 4:
>   Connects to the database on server
>   directly via the hostname/port.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-driver-types.htm) describe the difference between the 4 types of driver clearly. You may want to take a look at it.

Type 2 driver is database specific, as said in the article in the above link:

> The distinctive characteristic of type 2 jdbc drivers are that Type 2 drivers convert JDBC calls into database-specific calls i.e. this driver is specific to a particular database. Some distinctive characteristic of type 2 jdbc drivers are shown below. Example: Oracle will have oracle native api.

Answer (score 0):

> I have listened that type 2 driver
>   needs some database library's apis.

Yes. Type 2 drivers convert JDBC calls into database-specific calls means this is specific to a particular database. For example- Oracle will have its own oracle native driver API. While the Type 4 uses java networking libraries to communicate directly with the database server.

Comment: means for this type 2 driver oracle should be installed at sytem where our application is running and is it platform dependent?

Comment: @Bhadri: not necessary to install oracle on same machine. no this is not platform dependent.